# Determinate of a Singular 4x4 matrix is non zero using numpy det

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I am trying to calculate the determinate of the (4x4) matrix A using `np.linalg.det([A])`

Here A is defined as below

```
    import numpy as np
    A = np.array([
            [1, 3, 1, 2],
            [5, 8, 5, 3],
            [0, 4, 0, 0],
            [2, 3, 2, 8]
        ], dtype=np.float_)
```

if i run this

```
np.linalg.det([A])
```

I am getting the value as `array([-4.4408921e-15])` which seems to be wrong in my sense.
Because the Matrix A's 1st and 3rd column are same from my understanding of singular matrix if the columns are same i should get the det value as 0 but here i am getting a non zero value, what am i missing ?

Comment: Depending on your system, `4e-15` is very small and could be counted as precision error.

Comment: is that it..  because when i take dtype=int32/16 still i get -4.4408921 x 10^-15 , i  hope this is normal.

Comment: Determinant is **not** an integer operations, whatever your data type is, it will be converted to float.

Comment: Never thought this way, thanks for the insight, this answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of an accuracy. Try `float64`.

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([
        [1, 3, 1, 2],
        [5, 8, 5, 3],
        [0, 4, 0, 0],
        [2, 3, 2, 8]
    ], dtype=np.float64)

np.linalg.det([A])
```

Answer (score 0):

#write a customer function to find determinate

```
def det_mat(m1): 
    if (len(m1)!=len(m1[0])): 
        return "Error this is not a square matrix"
     elif (len(m1) == 2):
        return (m1[0][0]*m1[1][1] - m1[0][1]*m1[1][0])
     elif (len(m1) == 3):
      # | m00 m01 m02|          
      # | m10 m11 m12 | 
      # | m20 m21 m22 |
          a=  m1[0][0]* (m1[1][1]* m1[2][2] - m1[2][1]* m1[1][2]) 
          b=  m1[0][1]* (m1[1][0]* m1[2][2] - m1[2][0]*m1[1][2]) 
          c=  m1[0][2]* (m1[1][0]* m1[2][1] - m1[2][0]*m1[1][1])                     
          return(a-b+c)     
    elif (len(m1) == 4):
     # |m00 m01 m02 m03|          
     # |m10 m11 m12 m13| 
     # |m20 m21 m22 m23|
     #| m30 m31 m32 m33|
        a1=0
        a2=0
        a3=0 
        a4=0   
        a1= m1[0][0]* (m1[1][1]* (m1[2][2]* m1[3][3] - m1[3][2]* m1[2][3]) - m1[1][2]* (m1[2][1]* m1[3][3] - m1[3][1]*m1[2][3])+  m1[1][3]* (m1[2][1]* m1[3][2] - m1[3][1]*m1[2][2]))
     print(a1)   
        a2= m1[0][1]* (m1[1][0]* (m1[2][2]* m1[3][3] - m1[3][2]* m1[2][3]) - m1[1][2]* (m1[2][0]* m1[3][3] - m1[3][0]*m1[2][3])+ m1[1][3]* (m1[2][0]* m1[3][2] - m1[3][0]*m1[2][2])) 
     #print(a2)   
        a3= m1[0][2]* (m1[1][0]* (m1[2][1]* m1[3][3] - m1[3][1]* m1[2][3]) - m1[1][1]* (m1[2][0]* m1[3][3] - m1[3][0]*m1[2][3])+  m1[1][3]* (m1[2][0]* m1[3][1] - m1[3][0]*m1[2][1])) 
      #print(a3)   
        a4= m1[0][3]* (m1[1][0]* (m1[2][1]* m1[3][2] - m1[3][1]* m1[2][2]) - m1[1][1]* (m1[2][0]* m1[3][2] - m1[3][0]*m1[2][2])+  m1[1][2]* (m1[2][0]* m1[3][1] - m1[3][0]*m1[2][1]))
     #print(a4)
     return a1-a2+a3-a4
```

Comment: bb = [[1, 3, 1, 2], [5, 8, 5, 3], [0, 4, 0, 0], [2, 3, 2, 8]]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).