# Numpy returns nonzero determinant for singular matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, determinants

I have a function `coef_matrix(L)` that returns a square array whose elements are -1, 0 or 1 for which I expect that the columns (or rows) are not all linearly independent. Indeed, for all inputs I tested, the matrix rank calculated through `numpy.linalg.matrix_rank()` is equal to the matrix dimension minus 2 (e.g., the rank is 52 for a 54 x 54 matrix). Therefore, the returned matrices are singular. However, the determinant evaluates to nonzero values using `numpy.linalg.det()`. For the 54 x 54 matrix, it evaluates to `-1.046741523862728e-26`, which could lead me to think that this is zero apart from numerical error [as suggested here for a very similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63766815/determinate-of-a-singular-4x4-matrix-is-non-zero-using-numpy-det). But for higher dimenions not only the value gets markedly different from zero but it increases very fast: `-7.450540694504111` for 294 x 294, `-6.775526088295892e+24` for 486 x 486, and goes to `-inf` for dimensions greater than ~3000.

I'm very confident that the rank evaluation is correct as I have explicitly found the two linearly dependent columns for smaller cases. Does anyone know any reason that might explain this possible error for calculating the determinant with `numpy.linalg.det()`?

Comment: Are the elements that are -1, 0, or 1 chosen randomly? If so, are you sure it's singular? The larger the matrix is the less likely a random selection of rows/columns will match and produce a singular matrix.

Comment: Even if the matrix is integer dtype. `np.linalg.det` returns a float, e.g. `0.0` of `5.0000000001`.  So the float point error is to be expected.  For a random (294,294) array I get a det on the order of `e273`.  So the best you can expect in singular case would be some relatively small value compared to that.

Comment: @jared no, they are not random, the matrix represents the coefficient matrix of a system of linear equations.